# creating a trigger that updates row in a linked mysql server

Tags: sql

i created a linked Mysql server on SQL server 2008 r2. i'm trying to create a trigger on sql table that automatically updates a field in the linked server table, i have a table called "QFORCHOICE" in sql that has fields "Prodcode,prodname and avqty" and a table "que_for_choie" in mysql that has fields "procode,proname and avqty"
i want the trigger to update the value of "procode" in the linked server if the value of  "prodcode" in sql server changes. this is what i have so far but it has errors,

```
 create trigger [QFORCHOICE]
 ON dbo.QFORCHOICE
  FOR INSERT
   AS
    DECLARE @prodcode numeric(18,0)
    DECLARE @prodname varchar(50)
    DECLARE @avqty numeric(18,0)

    BEGIN
        SELECT
        @procode = procode,
        @proname = proname,
        @avqty = avqty
        FROM inserted

        update [LINKED_MYSQL].[que_for_choice]
        SET prodname=@prodname,avqty=@avqty
        WHERE prodcode = @prodcode
    end
```

can anybody please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, looking at you query I think you missing someting on this line "update [LINKED_MYSQL].[que_for_choice]". Normally, you'll write [Linked_serverName].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]

Comment: Does "SQL server 2008 r2" mean "Windows Server 2008 r2"?

Comment: the error message says "Invalid object name 'LINKED_MYSQL.Intelimenu.dbo.que_for_choice' . "LINKED_MYSQL"is the name of the linked server "Intelimenu is the Database name

Comment: @ jarlh,  Microsoft SQL server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  From within a trigger, you shouldn't attempt to access anything external to the current database. It will severely slow down any insert activity, and if there are any networking issues or the remote server is down for any reason, you'll then cause the original transaction to roll back. This is rarely the right thing to do

2- you're making the reliability of your system dependent on the reliability of two servers rather than one (say they both have 99% reliability - your system that ties them together with a trigger now has 98% overall reliability).